# Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string - React AJAX delete request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I can't figure out why this is throwing `Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string` in the console. I'm using React v15 and jQuery v3.

[image]

Here's my React code:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  handleDelete: function(comment) {
    console.log(comment);
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'DELETE',
      data: comment,
      contentType:'application/json',
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({ data: data });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({data: comments});
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(comment => {
      return(
        <div key= { comment.id }>
          <Comment author = { comment.author }>
            { comment.text }
          </Comment>
          <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>delete</button>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The json file looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1388534400000,
        "author": "Pete Hunt",
        "text": "Hey there!"
    },
    {
        "id": 1323434400000,
        "author": "Ben Jerry",
        "text": "I did a thing"
    },
    ...
    ...
]
```

Comment: what is in `err` variable of `error` callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing the comment to handleDelete, it is actually receiving the click event instead. You could probably get away with just using the comment id. Try this for the list renderer:

```
<div key= {comment.id}>
  <Comment author ={comment.author}>
    {comment.text}
  </Comment>
  <button onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, comment)}>delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're correct, it wasn't passing the actual comment. I've updated my code and it's passing the correct info, but now it's throwing `undefined "error" "Bad Request"` on the ajax call.

Comment: Which means that `this.props.url` is undefined, according to your code, which would explain the bad request.