# React Fragment serializing. Error: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this error when trying to render a React.Fragment:

ERROR:

```
Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
```

Part of code being passed to a component:

```
render{
    const block = {
      type : 'menu',
      className: 'c-header-nav__item c-header-nav__item--lv1',
      content: (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Link to = "https://www.google.com" title = "replace this dummy text" className = "c-header-nav__link" icon = "c-header-nav__item-icon js-show-submenu" >Áreas de negocio</Link>
        <div className="c-header-nav__submenu">
          <List className = "c-header-nav__item c-header-nav__item--lv2" type = "headerNavItem" elements = {[
            {
              className: "prueba",
              content: "hola"
            }
          ]} />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>)
    }


  return (
    <div>
      <AnyComponent block = {block} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Rendering of content part inside the AnyComponent that is receiving it:

```
<div>
  { this.props.block.content }
</div>
```

I have no idea why it is happening, but it might be a bug.

My React and ReactDom versions are:

```
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
```

Comment: Can you show us more code? It is not clear to me where `this.props.block` came from and how you are using it on the component that you are passing the data into. You could take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977046/cannot-convert-a-symbol-value-to-a-string-react-ajax-delete-request if it helps

Comment: @falinsky nothing to do with Enzyme or Jest. People commenting on those issues talk about an update of enzyme that fixed the problem...

Comment: @ickyrr I will edit the question, however, this.props.block contains the object that you can see above (the React.Fragment part)

Comment: I edited the question. Please check, thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried replicating the issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mksklc?file=Hello.js), it's working fine on my end. Take a look at my sample and tell me which part I did wrong.

Comment: I think I found the problem and you are right. Let me keep going and I will ellaborate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

My project is a repository of components using **storybook**, and turns out that passing fragments **through stories** is not supported.

I didn't have the time to explore why this is happening or opening an Issue on github, however, as soon as I am passing my fragments and rendering them like here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mksklc?file=Hello.js

Everything works out as expected.

Cheers

Comment: More info on that: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6147